# How to Define a Sort in Z3 Java API?

Tags: java, z3, smt

How do I define a sort in the Z3 Java API? I need to do a something like the following:

```
(define-sort Set (T) (Array T Bool))
```

Comment: I hope it helps: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classcom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3_1_1_sort.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples in https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/java/JavaExample.java

In particular:
https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/java/JavaExample.java#L1711-L1830

is a fully worked out example for a parametric tree representation.

Comment: I used that example but the SMTLIB generated by it only has `declare-datatypes` but no `define-sort`s.

Comment: Thee example shows how to define a Datatype (algebraic data type), which is not the same as either `declare-sort` or `define-sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are not part of the API as much as I was able to gather. Because, in a program, you can define a program variable to hold the sort and then use that variable anywhere you need it. A generic sort can be a represented as a function.

*E.g.*

```java
Sort set(Sort T) { return new ArraySort(ctx, T, new BoolSort()); }
```

In contrast, if you want to *declare* an uninterpreted sort, use

```
new UninterpretedSort(ctx, ctx.mkSymbol("sort_name"));
```

In the above `ctx` is your `Context` instance.